# R error in mutate(across()), Can't subset columns that don't exist

Tags: r, mutate, across

my apologies I am very new to coding.

I have two dataframes (unique*_*pt_all, denom_2011) with the same columns but different number of rows of patients:

```
> colnames(unique_pt_all)
> [1] "DESY_SORT_KEY"                   "STATE_CODE"                      "COUNTY_CODE"  
> [4] "SEX_CODE"                        "RACE_CODE"                       "AGE"  
> [7] "REFERENCE_YEAR"                  "C_DRY_EYE_COUNT"                 "C_SJOGRENS_COUNT"  
> [10] "C_AA_KERATACONJUNCTIVITIS_COUNT" "C_DIABETES_MELLITUS_COUNT"       "C_POA_GLAUCOMA_COUNT"  
> [13] "C_CICATRIZING_COUNT"             "C_CORNEAL_DISORDER_LENS_COUNT"   "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_COUNT"  
> [16] "C_CATARACT_COUNT"                "C_KERATOPLASTY_COUNT"            "C_PTERYGIUM_COUNT"  
> [19] "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_MIN_DT"          "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_MAX_DT"          "C_CATARACT_MIN_DT"  
> [22] "C_KERATOPLASTY_MIN_DT"           "C_PTERYGIUM_MIN_DT"
```

I want to add all of the values in columns 8-18 from dataframe "denom_2011" to the existing values in the same columns in dataframe "unique_pt_all" if the value in column "DESY_SORT_KEY" in "denom_2011" match AND the value in column "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_COUNT" is <= 2 in dataframe "unique_pt_all".

I've tried:

```
columns_to_add <- c(
  "C_DRY_EYE_COUNT",
  "C_SJOGRENS_COUNT",
  "C_AA_KERATACONJUNCTIVITIS_COUNT",
  "C_DIABETES_MELLITUS_COUNT",
  "C_POA_GLAUCOMA_COUNT",
  "C_CICATRIZING_COUNT",
  "C_CORNEAL_DISORDER_LENS_COUNT",
  "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_COUNT",
  "C_CATARACT_COUNT",
  "C_KERATOPLASTY_COUNT",
  "C_PTERYGIUM_COUNT"
)

# Update values based on conditions
unique_pt_all <- unique_pt_all %>%
  left_join(denom_2011 %>% filter(C_CORNEAL_ULCER_COUNT <= 2),
            by = "DESY_SORT_KEY",
            suffix = c("_unique", "_denom")) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(columns_to_add), 
                ~ifelse(is.na(.x_unique), .x, .x_unique + .x_denom))) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_denom"))
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(...)`.
Caused by error in `all_of()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `C_DRY_EYE_COUNT`, `C_SJOGRENS_COUNT`, `C_AA_KERATACONJUNCTIVITIS_COUNT`, `C_DIABETES_MELLITUS_COUNT`, `C_POA_GLAUCOMA_COUNT`, etc. don't exist.
```

Edit: Including the column names after left join:

> colnames(unique_pt_all)
> [1] "DESY_SORT_KEY"                          "STATE_CODE_unique"
> [3] "COUNTY_CODE_unique"                     "SEX_CODE_unique"
> [5] "RACE_CODE_unique"                       "AGE_unique"
> [7] "REFERENCE_YEAR_unique"                  "C_DRY_EYE_COUNT_unique"
> [9] "C_SJOGRENS_COUNT_unique"                "C_AA_KERATACONJUNCTIVITIS_COUNT_unique"
> [11] "C_DIABETES_MELLITUS_COUNT_unique"       "C_POA_GLAUCOMA_COUNT_unique"
> [13] "C_CICATRIZING_COUNT_unique"             "C_CORNEAL_DISORDER_LENS_COUNT_unique"
> [15] "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_COUNT_unique"           "C_CATARACT_COUNT_unique"
> [17] "C_KERATOPLASTY_COUNT_unique"            "C_PTERYGIUM_COUNT_unique"
> [19] "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_MIN_DT_unique"          "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_MAX_DT_unique"
> [21] "C_CATARACT_MIN_DT_unique"               "C_KERATOPLASTY_MIN_DT_unique"
> [23] "C_PTERYGIUM_MIN_DT_unique"              "STATE_CODE_denom"
> [25] "COUNTY_CODE_denom"                      "SEX_CODE_denom"
> [27] "RACE_CODE_denom"                        "AGE_denom"
> [29] "REFERENCE_YEAR_denom"                   "C_DRY_EYE_COUNT_denom"
> [31] "C_SJOGRENS_COUNT_denom"                 "C_AA_KERATACONJUNCTIVITIS_COUNT_denom"
> [33] "C_DIABETES_MELLITUS_COUNT_denom"        "C_POA_GLAUCOMA_COUNT_denom"
> [35] "C_CICATRIZING_COUNT_denom"              "C_CORNEAL_DISORDER_LENS_COUNT_denom"
> [37] "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_COUNT_denom"            "C_CATARACT_COUNT_denom"
> [39] "C_KERATOPLASTY_COUNT_denom"             "C_PTERYGIUM_COUNT_denom"
> [41] "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_MIN_DT_denom"           "C_CORNEAL_ULCER_MAX_DT_denom"
> [43] "C_CATARACT_MIN_DT_denom"                "C_KERATOPLASTY_MIN_DT_denom"
> [45] "C_PTERYGIUM_MIN_DT_denom"

Comment: Examine your output after the join. I bet that since "DESY_SORT_KEY" is your joining key, some of the other columns will be found in both tables and will be renamed like COMMON_COLUMN.x and COMMON_COLUMN.y, which won't be in your list of `columns_to_add`.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your comment. I've included the output columns after the join and am still unsure where the error lies. It seems like every column aside from DESY_SORT_KEY gets relabeled with _unique and _denom correctly

Comment: Oh I see. Still, it sounds like you are asking across() to perform operations on columns that don’t exist. C_DRY_EYE_COUNT is in the original tables but C_DRY_EYE_COUNT_unique and C_DRY_EYE_COUNT_denom are in the new tables.

Comment: I think this will be easier if you use bind_rows(unique = unique_pt_all, denom = denom_2011 %>% filter(C_CORNEAL_ULCER_COUNT <= 2), .id = “source”) to make a combined data set and then pivot longer based on the non-key variable and wider based on the source. That way you don’t have to mess with multiple associated names for the same variable.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will try the bind_rows method. Can you clarify what pivot longer and wider means?

Comment: @flammablewater https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html